# Using xcode to access rear camera, iphone iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios5, avcapture

I'm sorry if this is already answered...

All I need is how to fire up the rear facing camera and display it in an image view...no taking pictures, no accessing the photo library, just turning on the camera...simple.

I believe AVCapture is the thing to use, but anything I look into goes way deep than I need and I'm just not that smart.  Any help is appreciated.

THANKS!

Comment: See [UIImagePickerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)

Answer (score 0):

The [AVCam](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112) sample from Apple is the best place to start. Be warned that the seemingly simple task of displaying a live video preview from the camera is non-trivial.

Comment: fair enough...I appreciate the link.  This is a rare instance where I looking for the easy way out...